# Expression resolves to unused I Value

Tags: ios, swift, var, let

I am new to Swift and I am trying to change background colour of button.

I am using `chicken1` to change the background colour of the button all together

But I keep getting this error

> Expression resolves to unused I Value"

Here is the current code.

```
let chicken1 = button1; button2
chicken1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

Also should I use 'var' insted?

Comment: What's this? `button1; button2`

Comment: IBOutlet var button1: UIButton!
    IBOutlet var button2: UIButton!

Comment: That's not what I meant. What's `let chicken1 = button1; button2` supposed to do? You can't assign multiple values to a single variable (maybe you want tuples or arrays?)

Comment: i am using chicken1 to change the background colour of the button all togther

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, this isn't possible the way you are trying to do it.

One option is to loop through all of your buttons and change the background color in the loop.

```
for button in [button1, button2]{
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
}
```

---

The reason you are getting this error is because this line

```
let chicken1 = button1; button2
```

is the same as

```
let chicken1 = button1
button2 //this value isn't used
```

Swift doesn't actually need `;` at the end of a line like in other languages. By adding `;`, you tell Swift that you want to have multiple expressions on a single line.

The second line doesn't *do* anything because there are no function calls and no assignment, so it's like you want to *get* the value of `button2` but you don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

As Arc676 mention into comment you can't assign multiple values to a single variable.

So first way to achieve that is you can set background color individually as shown below:

```
button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

Or if you have array of button:

```
let chicken1 = [button1, button2]
for item in chicken1 {

    item.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for Swift 3 Xcode 8 use the code below

```
button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```

Or if you have array of button:

```
let chicken1 = [button1, button2]
for item in chicken1 {
    item.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
}
```